# Store data in couchbase using NodeJs and cradle

Tags: node.js, couchbase, cradle

I am trying to save data point in Couchbase Using cradle with NodeJs. Checkout this code :

```
var cradle = require('cradle'),db;
var connection = new(cradle.Connection)('localhost', 8091, {
    auth: { username: 'Admin', password: 'Admin' }
});

var db = connection.database('data');
db.save('exercise', {
   name: 'satyam',
   age: '24'
}, function (err, res) {
    if (err) {
        // Handle error
        console.log("SAVE ERROR: Could not save record!!");
    } else {
        // Handle success
        console.log("SUCESSFUL SAVE: The record was saved in CouchDB!");
    }
    console.log(res, new Date());
});
```

While executing this code I am getting msg :
SUCESSFUL SAVE: The record was saved in CouchDB!
{} Mon Mar 10 2014 17:57:09 GMT+0530 (IST)

Which seems like res is not having data. Can anybody help me out from this problem.

Comment: Is `exercise` a new document or an existed document?

Comment: Couchbase is not CouchDB. So first of all try to understand what you are using. If you're using CouchDB - write question about couchdb. If you're using couchbase - then use couchbase node client. PS: try reading docs first.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a wrong client. Cradle is a CouchDB client, whereas CouchBase is a different database. They have common root, so you are getting something that looks like it's almost working, but overall you are simply using a wrong tool.

Try using this instead: https://github.com/couchbase/couchnode

Comment: Thanks for helping. I solved this problem.

Best regards